# Convert Roman numerals to decimal with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to convert a Roman numeral into an integer (base 10) with JavaScript. Here is what I have so far.

```
var romanToInt = function(s) {
    var result =0;
    function b(q){
        var data = 0;

        switch(q){
            case 'I':
                data = 1;
                break;
            case 'V':
                data = 5;
                break;
            case 'X':
                data = 10;
                break;
            case 'L':
                data = 50;
                break;
            case 'C':
                data = 100;
                break;
            case 'D':
                data = 500;
                break;
            case 'M':
                data = 1000;
                break;
            }
        return data;  
    }

    var j =s.length;
    for(var i =0;i<j;i++){
        var m = b(s[j-2]);
        var n =b(s[j-1]);
        if(m<n){
            result = n-m;
       } else {
            result +=b(s[i]);
      }

    }
        return result;
}
```

The error message I receive is `SyntaxError: Unexpected token var`. I have no idea what points i missed. Thanks for your advice in advance.

Comment: It's hard to understand what your question is exactly. Also, I didn't get any syntax errors when I tested it.

Comment: Thank you McClain. I found the issue.

Comment: @pete consider updating your question with a solution for anyone who comes across this post

Comment: Please don't update your question with a solution. Instead post an answer and accept it. This will help others and will avoid confusion. In this case however it would be fitting to close as a typo.